# BlockingQueue program does not exit

Tags: java, multithreading

I was referring the concept of BlockingQue and I found one example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Thread/How_to_use_Java_BlockingQueue_with_multiple_threads.htm).

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue; /*  j  a  v a  2s . co  m*/
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        int capacity = 10;
        BlockingQueue < Integer > queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue < Integer > (capacity);

        int numWorkers = 2;
        Worker[] workers = new Worker[numWorkers];
        for (int i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
            workers[i] = new Worker(queue);
            workers[i].start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            queue.put(i);
        }
    }
}

class Worker extends Thread {
    BlockingQueue < Integer > q;

    Worker(BlockingQueue < Integer > q) {
        this.q = q;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Integer x = q.take();
                if (x == null) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

In the example, they have used only one thread which is a Worker thread.

What I understood about `BlockingQue` is that it is an alternate solution to **Producer-Consumer pattern**.

So we need two threads to work on. Hence I have doubts/questions.

Below are my questions.

1. have they used main thread as another thread?
2. When I run the application, the program does not get exited. I did not understand the reason why the main program does not exit?

Answer (score 2):

In the example code that you are referring , you have one **Producer** (`Main` Thread) and two **Consumers** (`Worker` Threads).

In Producer - Consumer problem, its not necessary to have only one Producer and only one Consumer - you can have multiple producers and multiple consumers. Their relative number is usually decided about who is doing more complex and time consuming tasks.

**Answer 1:** **main thread** is producer thread since it is being used to put items to `BlockingQueue`, `queue.put(i)`

**Answer 2:** your main thread exits after putting ten elements to queue but your worker thread keeps waiting for elements ( even after consuming ten elements ) because `q.take()` is a blocking method i.e. it waits for more elements to be put to queue (when `queue` is empty)

**Solution :** You need to put two `EOF` elements / `Objects` (`END OF FILE`) to queue and do a check like you did , `if (x == null)`. Try putting two extra nulls in queue so when your worker/consumer threads find it, they will terminate. Currently, your condition `if (x == null)` is never met.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1. No they have not used main thread for anything else. Main thread exit perfectly.

Answer 2. JVM does not exit until all the non-daemon thread ends. (Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

If you want the JVM to exit once the main thread finishes make your Worker threads to daemon thread by adding `workers[i].setDaemon(true);` inside your for loop.

The reason why your non-daemon threads doesn't exist is you have `Integer x = q.take();` inside while loop on Worker's run method. thus those Worker threads are forever waiting for new Integers to be put on the queue.

Suggestions: You can use Eclipse Java IDE to debug and see whats actually going on each thread